# Drools rule fires on events prior to the rule creation

Tags: java, drools

I'm loading a rule at run time but when I call fireAll, events that have been added prior to the rule are also triggered. Is there a way to only fire a rule on events that occurred after the rule was added?

Answer (score 0):

Clear working memory before you add the rule. The API lets you retrieve and retract all facts with a single, simple loop.

As an alternative, set an agenda filter before you insert the new rule. Run fireAllRules, remove the filter and continue as before.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to lose all facts, I just don't want the newly added rule to fire on old facts. It might be possible that another rule could use the old facts in the future (in conjunction with some new ones).

Comment: You are bound to create some inconsistencies unless you are executing stateless. But see the addition to my answer.